# How to unrar nested RAR files?

Tags: archive, rar

I have a recursive directory structure which contains a lot of RAR files. I have been using this `unrar` command to extract all contained files into the current working directory:

```
unrar e -r -o- *.rar
```

This is fine. How ever, some RAR files contain other RAR files, which are extracted by the above command. The problem is that the contents of these extracted RAR files do not get extracted, as the extracted RAR's are not part of the initial search.

How to go about this? I do not want to delete the first part of RAR files and do a new search. I'm not very fluent in Bash (or `#!/bin/sh -xu` which is the shebang of the script) but I'm thinking I want to save the file names of the first search and exclude them in the second command. (Max depth is RAR in RAR.) If there is not any more elegant solution?

Thank you in advance, Viktor.

Edit:

Trying the solution proposed by @icarus:

```
mkdir unrar
cd unrar
unrar e -r -o- ../*.rar
set -- *.rar
[ -e "$1" ] && unrar e -r -o- *.rar
```

Comment: Do you need to extract to the current directory? If not then make a new directory and change into it, extract the original rar files. extract from any rar files. 5 lines.

Comment: I think I do not, and I had not thought about that. Will definitely give it a try tomorrow if nothing else. Thank you!

Comment: @icarus I saw your edit, would you care to explain what `set -- *.rar` and `[ -e "$1" ]` does do exactly?

Comment: This handles the case where there are no rar files inside the original rar files. The `set -- *.rar` sets `$1` to the first rar file, `$2` to the second and so on. If there are none then it sets `$1` to the string `*.rar`. The `[ -e "$1" ]` tests to see if `$1` exists, and the `&&` says "run the thing on the left and if it works then run the thing on the right".

Comment: @icarus Hm, apparently the `-r` option does not seem to work for me, I thought it did. I only find and extract top-level RAR files.

Comment: What do you expect the `-r` to do?

Comment: Well, recursively search current and subdirectories for any files that match `*.rar`, But maybe I need to add `find` to the equation and exec `unrar` on each result. Having problem with getting the destination of extracted files to work though. As you said, I need that to not unrar the same files again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell (or find) to find the rar archives. Unpack the first set in a new directory, then unpack any that are in that directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob globstar
mkdir unrar
cd unrar
for i in ../**/*.rar ; do unrar e -o- "$i" ; done
for i in **/*.rar ; do unrar e -o- "$i" ; done
```